# Why these variables stop working if I put them outside of the function?

Tags: javascript

I'm a JavaScript beginner. I have the following:

```
  function countryType() {
    var country = $('#inputCountry').val();

    var visaFreeCountry90 = _.contains(visaFreeCountries90, country);
    var visaFreeCountry30 = _.contains(visaFreeCountries30, country);
    var specificCountry = _.contains(specificCountries, country);
    var specificCountryNIA = _.contains(specificCountriesNIA, country);

    if (visaFreeCountry90) {
      return '<p class="text-success">Visa-free Country 90 days</p>';
    } else if (visaFreeCountry30) {
      return '<p class="text-success">Visa-free Country 30 days</p>';
    } else if (specificCountry) {
      return '<p class="text-warning">Specific Country</p>';
    } else if (specificCountryNIA) {
      return '<p class="text-warning">Specific Country NIA</p>';
    } else {
      return '<p class="text-info">Regular Country</p>';
    }
  }
```

I want to put those variables outside of the function:

```
    var country = $('#inputCountry').val();

    var visaFreeCountry90 = _.contains(visaFreeCountries90, country);
    var visaFreeCountry30 = _.contains(visaFreeCountries30, country);
    var specificCountry = _.contains(specificCountries, country);
    var specificCountryNIA = _.contains(specificCountriesNIA, country);

    function countryType() {

    if (visaFreeCountry90) {
      return '<p class="text-success">Visa-free Country 90 days</p>';
    } else if (visaFreeCountry30) {
      return '<p class="text-success">Visa-free Country 30 days</p>';
    } else if (specificCountry) {
      return '<p class="text-warning">Specific Country</p>';
    } else if (specificCountryNIA) {
      return '<p class="text-warning">Specific Country NIA</p>';
    } else {
      return '<p class="text-info">Regular Country</p>';
    }
  }
```

But the if statement stops working if I do that. What's the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine the function is called on an event related to the input. If that's the case, move the `var country = $('#inputCountry').val();`, as well as the `_.contain` calls related to it, to inside the function.

As it is now, it runs once, before the user has entered a value on the input, so country is empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a parameter to a function

```
    var country = $('#inputCountry').val();

    var visaFreeCountry90 = _.contains(visaFreeCountries90, country);
    var visaFreeCountry30 = _.contains(visaFreeCountries30, country);
    var specificCountry = _.contains(specificCountries, country);
    var specificCountryNIA = _.contains(specificCountriesNIA, country);

    function countryType(visaFreeCountry90, visaFreeCountry30, specificCountry, specificCountryNIA) {

    if (visaFreeCountry90) {
      return '<p class="text-success">Visa-free Country 90 days</p>';
    } else if (visaFreeCountry30) {
      return '<p class="text-success">Visa-free Country 30 days</p>';
    } else if (specificCountry) {
      return '<p class="text-warning">Specific Country</p>';
    } else if (specificCountryNIA) {
      return '<p class="text-warning">Specific Country NIA</p>';
    } else {
      return '<p class="text-info">Regular Country</p>';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm curious, why is the reason I have to add them as arguments?

Comment: Imagine that a function is a country that needed visa, so if you want people (as parameters) to enter the country, they needed the visa to enter the function. XD!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use that variable inside that function pass it as the arguments to the function like:

```
function countryType(visaFreeCountry90,visaFreeCountry30,...)
```

And access it inside the function

Comment: Thanks, why I have to add them as arguments? I'm curious.

Comment: Because if the variables are declared outside the function definition it will be out of the scope of the function. So in order to access it we need to pass it as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Efficiency_considerations

```
function outside(x) {
   function inside(y) {
      return x + y;
   }
   return inside;
}
fn_inside = outside(3); 
result = fn_inside(5); // returns 8

result1 = outside(3)(5); // returns 8
```

### Preservation of variables

Notice how x is preserved when inside is returned. A closure must preserve the arguments and variables in all scopes it references. Since each call provides potentially different arguments, a new closure is created for each call to outside. The memory can be freed only when the returned inside is no longer accessible.

This is not different from storing references in other objects, but is often less obvious because one does not set the references directly and cannot inspect them.